# Highlighting commandbutton jsf 2.1 when pressed

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I am using JSF 2.1 to code a web application. I would like to use 2 buttons to take me to two different views passing a param. But by default I have one button "pressed" and therefore it should be "depressed" in the view. How can I show this sort of a bahaviour? here is the small piece of code where I have two buttons:

```
                                    <h:outputLabel value="Color:" />
                                    <!--blue button is highlighted as pressed by default -->
                                    <h:commandButton  value ="blue" action="#{bean.update}" >
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="blue" />
                                    </h:commandButton>

                                    <!--green button is highlighted as pressed when clicked -->
                                    <h:commandButton value ="green" action="#{bean.update}" >
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="de" />
                                    </h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any kind of style to your h:commandButton as you would do to a normal button. For example to have a disabled button feel you can just set the opacity of your first button by default.

```
<h:commandButton  value ="blue" action="#{bean.update}" 
                  style="opacity: 0.65" >
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="blue" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Or just add css class to your button using `styleClass` attribute

```
<h:commandButton  value ="blue" action="#{bean.update}" 
                  styleClass="pressedButtonStyle" >
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="blue" />
</h:commandButton>
```

To change the class of your second button you can use onClick function to add a new css style to the button:

```
<h:commandButton value ="green" action="#{bean.update}" onClick="$(this).addClass("pressedButtonStyle")" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="de" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you want to keep the state of buttons after returning to page you can apply these classes according to conditions such as this:

```
<h:commandButton  value ="blue" action="#{bean.update}" style="opacity : #{bean.color eq 'blue' ? 0.65 : 1}">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="blue" />
</h:commandButton>

<!--green button is highlighted as pressed when clicked -->
<h:commandButton value ="green" action="#{bean.update}"  style="opacity : #{bean.color eq 'de' ? 0.65 : 1}" >
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.color}" value="de" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thanks cubbuk! Just a doubt. I need to have button blue pressed by default and its action rendered per default. How can I show this?

Comment: So do you mean when the user enters the page, by default blue button will be automatically clicked and do the required action?

Comment: well actually, I set bean.color in my init() as blue, so i would like to see the button being pressed in my initial view

Comment: Well you can do that using javascript. You need to give an id to your button and using that id you can simulate a click event using javascript. <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function ()  {document.getElementById('idOfYourButton').click();
    }                   
    </script>